# View pager, recycler view Items get doubled in fragment if come back from another activity/fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I have *main activity* where 5 fragments are hosted with *view pager 2* (not slid able) and *bottom navigation*. First fragment's name is *home fragment*. Home fragment contains

**1 view pager :** Where some pics are shown from firebase (uses pager adapter)

**2 recycler views :** Where some items are shown also from firebase (on click takes to another activity)

**Issue :** When I browse through the fragments with bottom nav it works fine. But when I come from the *5th fragment(very last)* to the *1st fragment(home fragment)*, sometimes the items in view pager, recycler view get doubled with a flicker (seems like it re added items)
. The same thing also happens when I go to another activity and come back to it after some time.

Recycler View adapter

```
public class CourseListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseListAdapter.CourseListViewHolder> {

    public static final int HOME_PAGE = 1;
    public static final int DISPLAY_COURSE = 2;

    private Picasso mPicasso;

    private List<DisplayCourse> courseList;

    private static final String TAG = "CourseListAdapter";

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View view);
    }

    private String mSender;

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public CourseListAdapter(List<DisplayCourse> courseList, String sender) {
        this.courseList = courseList;
        this.mSender = sender;
        mPicasso = Picasso.get();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CourseListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        switch (viewType) {
            case 1:
                View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recom_course_home_layout, parent, false);
                return new CourseListViewHolder(view1, mListener);
            case 2:
                View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_course_layout, parent, false);
                return new CourseListViewHolder(view2, mListener);

            default:
                View view3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_video_item_layout, parent, false);
                return new CourseListViewHolder(view3, mListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CourseListViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.title.setText(courseList.get(position).getCourseTitle());

        mPicasso.load(courseList.get(position).getThumbnailURL())
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .into(holder.thumbnail, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        mPicasso.load(courseList.get(position).getThumbnailURL())
                                .error(R.drawable.ofklogo)
                                .into(holder.thumbnail, new Callback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess() {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Exception e) {

                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return courseList.size();
    }

    public static class CourseListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView title;

        public CourseListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.courseTitle);
            thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.courseThumbNailImageView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    if (listener != null) {
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position, view);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mSender.equals("home_page")) {
            return HOME_PAGE;
        } else if (mSender.equals("displayCourse")) {
            return DISPLAY_COURSE;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

In home fragment onCreateView() I am using this adapter

```
mainActivityViewModel.getRandomCourseLiveData_2().observe(this, new Observer<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DisplayCourse course = dataSnapshot.getValue(DisplayCourse.class);
                randomCourse_2.add(course);
                recom_course_2 = new CourseListAdapter(randomCourse_2, "home_page");
                binding.randomCourseRecyclerView2.setAdapter(recom_course_2);

                recom_course_2.setOnItemClickListener(new CourseListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(int position, View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CourseActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("section_name", "Arts");
                        intent.putExtra("course_name", randomCourse_2.get(position).getCourseTitle());
                        intent.putExtra("course_name_english", randomCourse_2.get(position).getCourseTitleEnglish());
                        intent.putExtra("from", "home");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: " + randomCourse_2.get(position).getCourseTitle());
                        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: " + randomCourse_2.get(position).getCourseTitleEnglish());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please provide your code examples, maybe RecyclerView.Adapter implementation and how you work with them.

Comment: I have added the adapter code. please check. I am trying to solve this for 2 days but no luck

Comment: Seems like everything is ok with your adapter. Please show where and how you use the adapter

Comment: @Link182 I am using view model to fetch data from firebase using firebase live data query like this example [link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components_22.html)

Answer (score 0):

You create and populate recycler view observing an `LiveData` object. `LiveData` in some circumstances fire the old events again when android component is recreated, even when view model is not recreated. Is a normal practice for google do semi-workable solutions, half of jetpack libs are shiny shit.

To solve this you have to swith to better observer library like rxJava or to do some workarounds, for example to wrap LiveData payload in an object like this https://github.com/Link184/ArchitectureMVVM/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/link184/architecture/mvvm/common/Event.kt and to observe it like here https://github.com/Link184/ArchitectureMVVM/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/link184/architecture/mvvm/base/MvvmContext.kt

```
myLiveData.postValue(Event(MyPaload()))

myLiveData.observe(myLifecycleOwner) { event: Event<MyPayload> ->
    event.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
        handleEvent(it)
    }
}
```

Another possible issue is maybe you accidentally fire event twice, is hard to say without to see the big picture.

Also a quick workaround is to remove duplicates from adapter, to obtain that you have only to change your `ArrayList` to `HashSet`

```
private Set<DisplayCourse> courseList
```

Just pass the items in adapter constructor as `HashSet`

Comment: thank you for your answer. can you please suggest me or point me to a direction where I can learn about using set in adapter class? I do not have any experience with sets.

Comment: I tried with the sets. I get the data as sets and send them to adapter. there I convert the set to array list to get the contents with position. list works fine. but it behaves like before. I don't understand. set only stores unique data. then how is this happening? I am so lost @link182

Comment: `dataSnapshot.getValue(DisplayCourse.class)` returns the right list of objects? I mean is without duplicates? Try to use debugger to see where/when the duplicates are added? Also I see you call `randomCourse_2.add(course)` please double check where/how adapter is used